# ContainerFromIndex returns null

Tags: c++-cli, win-universal-app

I am working in c++ windows universal platform. I need to access combobox items and change their property. So in the OnDropDownOpened method i am trying to access the combobox item and set property. But I am getting the comboboxitem null at the first open. I can see the combox has items in it. Here is my code :

```
void MainPage::OnDropDownOpened(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e)
{   
    ComboBox^ combobox = dynamic_cast<ComboBox^>(sender);
    int i = 0;
    for (auto item : combobox->Items)
    {
        ComboBoxItem^ comboboxItem;
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            comboboxItem = dynamic_cast<ComboBoxItem^>(combobox->ContainerFromIndex(i));

            if (comboboxItem !=nullptr)
            {                       
              comboboxItem->IsEnabled = true;
              comboboxItem->FontWeight = Windows::UI::Text::FontWeights::Bold;                  
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

When i click the dropdown i can see the comboboxItem is NULL but i have items in the combobox. It works fine from the second click. What's wrong with the **ContainerFromIndex** here?

Answer (score 1):

UpdateLayout call on the sender object worked for me :

```
void MainPage::OnDropDownOpened(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e)
{   
    ComboBox^ combobox = dynamic_cast<ComboBox^>(sender);
    combobox->UpdateLayout();
    int i = 0;
    for (auto item : combobox->Items)
    {
        ComboBoxItem^ comboboxItem;
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            comboboxItem = dynamic_cast<ComboBoxItem^>(combobox->ContainerFromIndex(i));

            if (comboboxItem !=nullptr)
            {                       
              comboboxItem->IsEnabled = true;
              comboboxItem->FontWeight = Windows::UI::Text::FontWeights::Bold;                  
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```